# How can I control y-axis ticks and x-axis ticks independently in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to remove axis ticks from the x-axis without removing them from the y-axis.

Right now, I can get both to be removed using:

```
axis.ticks=theme_blank()
```

For instance:

```
# Generate data
c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl)))

c + geom_bar()+opts(axis.ticks=theme_blank())
#c + geom_bar(width=.5)
#c + geom_bar() + coord_flip()
#c + geom_bar(fill="white", colour="darkgreen")
```

But I don't know how to control them independently.

Comment: BTW, if you're going to use an out of date version of **ggplot2** it would be helpful if you mentioned that in your questions.

Comment: In the latest version its gonna be `theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank())` for lets say the x axis ..

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To remove just x axis ticks use `axis.ticks.x=`

```
 c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) 
 c + geom_bar()+opts(axis.ticks.x=theme_blank())
```

For the latest ggplot2 version (0.9.3) instead of `opts()` use `theme()` and `element_blank()`.

```
 c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) 
 c + geom_bar()+theme(axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

Comment: Works for me! @arun, do you have the right version of ggplot2?

Comment: No, I over-read the question :). I thought it was axis-labels... just understood it's ticks! God I was staring at the plot for quite a while to see what's different! :)